# How to display:none to the after of the previous sibling using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

In my project I have a `menu` (list) , and after each `<li>` I insert an image , a small image of `divider` . 
I want when I hover the `<li>` (the menu class) to be able to display none also his previous sibling`:after`.

I have this :

```
.menu:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
```

How could i do that?

Comment: Previous siblings cannot be selected by CSS.

Comment: you should insert the upper divider as a background of the current `li:not(:first-child):before` so you would be able to manage the background on hover

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you inserted the image using the :after pseudo-class through the content attribute, eg :

```
.menu li:after {
content: 'url(path/to/your/image)';
}
```

So, for the hover state try this :

```
.menu li:hover:after {
content: none;
}
```